# Vue component watch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

all how i can watch changes in my component in data?
I need watch when user choose car brand to take from server models for that brand
this is my code
Templete

```
<template>
<div class="category-info">
    <div v-for="input in inputs.text">
        <label >{{ input.placeholder}}</label>
        <input type="text"  id="location" :name="input.name" v-model="input.value" @click="console">
    </div>
    <div class="select" v-for="select in inputs.select">
        <label >{{ select.placeholder }}</label>
        <my-select :data="select" v-model="select.value"></my-select>
    </div>
    <button @click="console">click</button>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "profile-add-inputs",
    props: ['category'],
    data() {
        return {
            inputs: {
                text : {},
                select: {}
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
       getCategories(){
           axios.get('/profile/inputs', {
               params: {
                   category: JSON.stringify(this.category.href)
                }
               })
                .then((response) => {
                   this.inputs.text = response.data.text;
                    this.inputs.select = response.data.select;
                    for(let key in this.inputs.text){
                        this.inputs.text[key].value = '';
                    }
                    for(let key in this.inputs.select){
                        this.inputs.select[key].value = '';
                        if(this.category.href.sub == 'car' && this.inputs.select[key].name == 'brand'){
                            console.log('CAR BREND');
                            this.$watch.inputs.select[key].value = function () {
                                console.log(this.inputs.select[key].value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },this)
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
       },
        console(){
            console.log(this.inputs.select);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        category : function () {
            this.getCategories();
            console.log('categoty');
        },
        inputs : {
            handler() {
                console.log('watch inputs');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, i tried to use watch and $watch but its not working, plz give me a reason why that not work, or maybe some another way to resolve this problem

this.$watch can i create dynamiclly watchers with this stement?

Comment: Is the `category` watch working? As that is the right way to use `watch`. The function accepts 2 params `inputs: function(val, oldVal){}`.

Comment: Yeah catehory watch working

Comment: so if watch is working then what is the problem?

Comment: just a quick guts feeling, if `category` is an object, make sure when you update it, make a new object out of it. Ex. category.splice() for array, category = [...category]. This might trigger the watch.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
watch : {
  inputs : function(val, oldVal){
     //val : New value
     //oldVal : Previous value.
  }
}
```

Comment: i know, but it`s not work too, no raction on changes

Comment: If this also doesn't work which mean there is some other issue in the code. Try creating a fiddle of your code.